# fwrite fails (returns 0, perror gives "Bad address")

Tags: c++, fwrite

What are the possible reasons for such an error. File being written to is created without a problem, but `fwrite` fails each time.

I am porting from 32-bit little endian to 64-bit big endian.

The structure I am writing is

```
struct Node 
{
uint8_t *a;
uint32_t *b;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t d;
uint32_t e;
uint32_t f;     
uint32_t g; 
uint16_t h; 
uint8_t i;  
uint8_t j;  
uint8_t k[MAX];
uint32_t (*l)[2];
uint32_t m; 
uint32_t n;

Node() {
    memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
    l = NULL;
    a = (uint8_t*)calloc(N,1);
}
~Node() {
    free(a);
    free(b);
}
};
```

The code writing the node is

```
void push(void *ptr)
{
Node *node = (Node *) ptr;
assert(fwrite(node, sizeof(Node), 1, fpw) == 1);
    free(node);
}
```

`fpw` has a global scope.

When I tried to debug, I found that `fwrite` returns 0 and `perror` gives "Bad address" as the error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Show where you allocate the pointer you're passing in to `push`.

Comment: That's wrong on so many levels...

Comment: @littleadv: Absolutely nothying can be said about this being "right" or "wrong" until the context and the purpose of the code is known. I don't think there's anything "real" about this code, considering the field names, field types and the rest. This code looks like an experiment made for the sake of experiment. Your "style & design" suggestions are defeating the purpose of the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have an answer for you here, but I think its worth pointing out a bunch of things that I see in your code. Solving them, I would hope, will help you overcoming your problem.

1. When you have a class that you want to dump into a file - have the class do the work for you. That means, your `Node` class will have a `write`/`read` set, or `operator<<`/`operator>>` or any other conventional set of routines that you will call, and have it serialize itself into a file and then deserialize itself from a file on read. Boost provides you [tools](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to help with that, as well.
2. Dumping a content of a class pointer is a dangerous thing, **especially** if you're dumping on one architecture, and reading on another (in your case 32LE vs 64BE). It will **most certainly** fail in a whole bunch of various unpredictable ways.
3. You access a pointer you got from somewhere without verifying its valid. I don't know if you have a test on your `ptr` before you call `push`, but I'm sure it will be helpful to check the pointer in `push` itself, especially if the error suggests it might not be good.
4. You're writing C++ code. You're destroying a class. **`free`** shouldn't be anywhere in your code! You're creating `Node* node` with `malloc`? I would hope not! If you're using `new` you **must** use `delete`.
5. You're freeing `a` and `b` in your `~Node`, but you don't allocate them anywhere. If you're not allocating it in the constructor - when you delete it in the destructor - **verify** that you allocated them, otherwise you'll get bunch of undefined behavior here too.

Just some things that couldn't help but noticing, hope it helps.